# making groups with random names in it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, shuffle

I am new to coding Javascript. I am trying to to shuffle list of names inputted on a textarea. The user selects the number of groups desired, and shuffle on click, then show the divided groups as output result. Below is my code but it is not working as it should be, pls help!

```
<script>

    function ArrayToGroups(source, groups){
        var groupList = [];

        groupSize = Math.ceil(source.length/groups);

        var queue = source;

        for(var r = 0; r < groups; r++){
            groupList.push(queue.splice(0,groupSize));
        }
        return groupList;
    }

    function textSpliter(splitText){

        var textInput = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        var splitText = textInput.split(',');

        var newList = []; 

        for(x = 0; x <= splitText.length; x++) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * splitText.length);

            var p = splitText[random];
            newList.push(p);

            splitText.splice(p,groupList);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < newList.length; i++){

            var s = newList[i];
            document.getElementById('resInput').value += s + "\n" ;
        }

        return splitText;
    }



</script>

Below is my input and output textareas

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <textarea id="inputText" placeholder="text" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="number" name="number" max="6" value="1" id="groupNumber">
    <textarea id="resInput" placeholder="text" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="Shuffle" value="shuffle" onclick="textSpliter()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the code so my html code with my input,output and the shuffle-button is there as well.

Comment: Make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code. Give an example input such as "Josh,Adam,Chris..." and example output (how you want to group them, the end result).

Comment: My output should look like this:

    'group 1 - Thomas,Linda,Jonah
    group 2 - Andreas,Benjamin,Robin'

The names are inputted in a textarea. The user chooses his desired number of groups, then javascript will shuffle and sort the names into groups, and then results will be displayed on the second textarea with the ID resInput.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/518b000u/

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffle() {

    // Get list
    // Example: element1, element 2, ele ment 3, ...
    var list = document.getElementById("inputText").value.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ",").split(",");

    // Get number of groups
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("groupNumber").value);

    // Calculate number of elements per group
    var m = Math.floor(list.length / n);

    // Enought elements
    if (n * m == list.length) {

        // Create groups
        var groups = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            groups[i] = new Array();

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

                // Random
                rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);

                // Add element to group
                groups[i][j] = list[rand];

                // Remove element to list
                list.splice(rand, 1);
            }

        }

        // Output
        var text = "";

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            text += "Group " + (i + 1) + ": ";

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {

                if (j != 0) { text += ", "; }
                text += groups[i][j];

            }

            text += "\n";

        }

        document.getElementById("resInput").value = text;

    } else {

        alert("Add more elements");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code. It's pretty self-explanatory.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/518b000u/1/)

```
function textSpliter() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    var names = input.split(",");

    var groupSize = document.getElementById("groupNumber").value;
    var groupCount = Math.ceil(names.length / groupSize);
    var groups = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
        var group = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < groupSize; j++) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
            var name = names[random];
            if (name != undefined) {
                group.push(name);
                names.splice(names.indexOf(name), 1);
            }
        }
        group.sort();
        groups.push(group);
    }
    printGroups(groups);
}

function printGroups(group) {
    var output = document.getElementById("resInput");
    output.value = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        var currentGroup = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < group[i].length; j++) {
            currentGroup = group[i].join(",");
        }
        output.value += currentGroup + "\r";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 version ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/dLgpny5z/1/

```
function textSpliter() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  var names = input.replace(/\s*,\s*|\n/g, ",").split(",");

  var groupSize = document.getElementById("groupNumber").value;
  var groupCount = Math.ceil(names.length / groupSize);
  var groups = [...Array(groupCount)].map(() => Array());

  var i = 0
  while (names.length > 0) {
    var m = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
    groups[i].push(names[m]);
    names.splice(m, 1);
    i = (i >= groupCount - 1) ? 0 : i + 1
  }
  printGroups(groups);
}

function printGroups(groups) {
  var output = document.getElementById("resInput");
  output.value = groups.map(group => group.join(',')).join('\r');
}
```